# How is group membership determined in a Wildfly cluster of standalone servers?

Tags: wildfly

I have seen that a cluster can be formed/started very easily with Wildlfy. Is it possible using "standalone" configuration to create multiple clusters? That is some servers should only be part of a cluster named "cluster1" and other servers should form a different cluster named "cluster2". That is can a group name or similar be provided or configured? (I am not looking for a managed domain setup).

Comment: I think I have found a way forward by changing multicast addresses, will update with my own answer if it works out

Comment: Or even a simple port offset might do the trick

Answer (score 1):

By specifying different multicast-addresses, that is each cluster has its own multicast-address. Port offsets don't affect the cluster but might be necessary to avoid port conflicts (when starting multiple Wildfly instances on a single machine).

```
jboss.default.multicast.address //controls the multicast address
```